# Deploy Solution in SharePoint 2013

Tags: solution-deployment

I am deploying a SharePoint solution in SharePoint 2013 and I am getting the error: "a web config modification is already running"

Environment is multiple servers (4), and multiple web application (5). The error message indicates a different server each time. I have confirmed the timer service and admin service is running on all servers.

On each failure I have to "force" deployment and then retract to clean up. I have restarted all servers in farm and no success.

(I don't think it is related to this specific solution, but here is a little more detail)
The solution was actually for SharePoint 2010 (http://siteworkflow.codeplex.com/). I did find the discussion for the 2007 version of this same solution. (http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/discussions/430733).

I tried the suggestions in there about using the -CompatabilityLevel switch and same issue.

Has anyone seen similar issue, know why it fails, or how to get past issue.

Comment: To validate whether this issue is only with that solution. Try to deploy a test solution file and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I did both the 2010 version linked above and the 2007 version linked above (both have different names and code). I am trying to hunt down another simple solution, to try with.